# Add JSON Data into radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got a JSON object that store data.

```
var quiz= {question: [
    {Question: "Question 1?", 
        answers: [
            {answer: "Answer 1", correct_answer: 0},
            {answer: "Answer 2", correct_answer: 1},
            {answer: "Answer 3", correct_answer: 0}
    ]}
]};
```

and I want that to radio buttons. I also want it to be dynamic, since I may add another question or so. Whats the way to do so? I'm new a javascript/jquery so I'm still learning how this works. Thank for your help.

Comment: You want the questions to randomly be given? Or the answers?

Comment: The answers. I've already got the Question to stick to a h2-tag. 'document.getElementById("title").innerText=currentQuestion.Question;' But I can't figur out how to do the same with the answers

Comment: Isn't is bad idea to pass correct_answer flag to client?

Comment: You just should iterate answers array. By a loop. For example, `for`. And build your html as a string. When this is done - inject this html. For example with `appendTo` method

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. i've been seens lots of questions related to `quiz` over the past few weeks... is it some sort of project or something in any school/colleges? why the rush over `quiz` sites? can somebody enlighten me? :p

Comment: I've got this loop.'var answers=currentQuestion.answers;
      for (var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
             var answer=answers[i].answer; // current answer
             
      }' but cant figur out how to stick it to radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data field like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="somename" id="someid" value="somevalue" data-correct-answer="true" />
```

You can specify any data attribute name as long as it's prefixed with `data-` as per HTML5 specs.

In jQuery, these can then be retrieved using the `.data()` function, such as:

```
var isCorrect = $('#someid').data('correct-answer');
```

I guess this could work as long as you don't mind that the user can inspect the DOM and see the right answers.